# Errors with trying to run a stored procedure with local file output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, collation, csv, bcp

I'm trying to run a stored procedure that I'm passing some variables to.

The output is being writted to a CSV file on a local file share.

The CSV file gets created, but I'm hitting some errors that I'm not sure how to resolve.  Any help would be appreciated.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @tmp1 DATETIME
SET @tmp1 = DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

DECLARE @tmp2 DATETIME
SET @tmp2 = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))

DECLARE @fac_ids NVARCHAR(500)
SET @fac_ids = '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,30,32,33,35,36,37,40,41,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,79,80,81,83,84,85,86,87,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,97,98,135,39,29,31,34'

DECLARE @start_date DATETIME
SET @start_date = @tmp1

DECLARE @end_date DATETIME
SET @end_date = @tmp2

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(max)
SET @sql = 'Exec [dbo].[sproc_ar_reconciliation] @fac_ids, @start_date, @end_date'

DECLARE @CsvFile NVARCHAR(500)
SET @CsvFile = 'C:\DOMO\AROS\ar_recon.csv'

DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000) 
SET @cmd = 
'bcp '+CHAR(34)+@sql+CHAR(34)+' queryout '+CHAR(34)+@CsvFile+CHAR(34)+' -S '+@@servername
+' -c -t'+CHAR(34)+','+CHAR(34)+' -r'+CHAR(34)+'\n'+CHAR(34)+' -T'

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

**Errors**

> NULLStarting copy... SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 137 Error =
>   [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]

`Must declare the scalar variable "@fac_ids"`.

> SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0]`

`Unable to resolve column level collations NULL BCP copy out failed NULL`

Comment: the problem is that the string that forms is something like this
bcp "Exec [dbo].[sproc_ar_reconciliation] '@fac_ids, '@start_date, '@end_date" queryout "C:\DOMO\AROS\ar_recon.csv"
so the parameters have no data

Comment: ...and the collation issues probably have something to do with the queries inside the procedure, which we can't help with unless we can see that...

Comment: Any suggestions on how I should build the string?  I dont think the issue is with the  queries inside the SP.  When I run "exec [dbo].[sproc_ar_reconciliation] with '@fac_ids, '@start_date, '@end_date".   I receive the correct data output.

Comment: '@start_date, '@end_date I think you could calculate it within the sp and just send '@fac_ids in your string with a small modification it all depends if '@start_date,' '@end_date you can calculate it inside